# Array of numbers in Dart without using List?

Tags: arrays, list, dart

In Dart, I need to have a list of numeric values, and in my case, this list never needs to have any special operations done (does not need re-ordering, length queries, add, etc.) on them other than reading the values with one sweep.

Is there an alternative data structure to List where we could store a "list" like this and compare two of them using == or != and not suffer the performance hit of having to use "deep equality"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dart, you need to use the `List` type to represent an array.

The `==` operator doesn't use "deep equality" and will just check if two lists are the same object.

```dart
List<int> a = [1, 2, 3];
List<int> b = [1, 2, 3];
print(a == b); // false
```

Fortunately, you can get around this issue without the performance hit of looping through both lists by using the `const` keyword:

```dart
List<int> c = const [4, 5, 6];
List<int> d = const [4, 5, 6];
print(c == d); // true
```

Comment: Thanks.  Isn't that "identical" function doing some expensive deep comparison stuff though?  Why does this work?

Comment: edited the answer based on something I learned just now :)

Comment: @NerdyBunz [`identical`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/identical.html) only ever checks if two objects are the same object.  That's all it can ever do.  [The default implementation of `operator ==`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) is the same as `identical`.